# Tensorflow / Keras CNN errors "Function call stack: distributed_function"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm working on a CNN and once the first epoch is completed I am getting the error messages:

```
"Function call stack: distributed_function"
```

and

```
"Fused conv implementation does not support grouped convolutions for now."
```

I am using slightly modified code that I used for another CNN that worked on the previous one so I'm a bit lost as to why this error is occurring now.

The images I am using are grey scale heat map images similar to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBmLF.png)

Code:

```
TRAINING_DIR = '/Users/me/School/Research/mini'
training_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale = 1./255,
    rotation_range=40,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest')

train_generator = training_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    TRAINING_DIR,
    target_size=(640,480),
    class_mode='categorical'
)

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # Input shape is the desired size of the image 640x480 with 1 byte color
    # This is the first convolution
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', input_shape=(640, 480, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2, 2), # factors to downscale by, (2,2) will halve
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu'),   # 2nd convo layer
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),  # 3rd convo layer
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), activation='relu'),  # 4th convo layer
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(2,2),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),            # Flatten to DNN
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),      # hidden layer 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation='softmax')      # 3 class 
])

model.summary()
model.compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(train_generator, epochs=15, verbose = 1)
model.save("rps.h5")

acc = history.history['accuracy']
loss = history.history['loss']
epochs = range(len(acc))
```

Comment: I guess the problem is using `model.fit` If you are not using the current tensorflow version, then you should use `model.fit_generator`

Comment: I get the same error either way. My TF version is 2.1.0 and Keras version is 2.2.4-tf

Answer (score 1):

For me this turned out to be a TensorFlow version issue. I was using 2.x when I should have been using 1.13.2. To fix it, I did this BEFORE doing "import tensorflow as tf":

```
 !pip install tensorflow==1.13.2
```

This solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing `input_shape=(640, 480, 1)` to `input_shape=(640, 480, 3)`